# How do I make square brackets in a chemical formula?

Tags: brackets, chemistry

I want to write the concentration of chlorine ions inside a cell as
`[Cl-]i`, with the `-` superscripted and the `i` subscripted. I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  while i'm not a chemist, i believe that the `mhchem` package can help you.

Comment: The `utf8` in `inputenc` package is for special characters and accents, it is not necessary for superscript format.

Comment: Try `[Cl\textsuperscript{-}]\textsubscript{i}`

Comment: Or `$[\mathrm{Cl}^-]_i$`

Answer (score 8):

As already pointed out by barbara beeton in the comments, this can easily be done using the `mhchem` package as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{[Cl^-]_i}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use the `chemformula` package as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\ch{[Cl^-]_i}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out in the comments by thymaro, `mhchem` yields an italic `i` while `chemformula` yields an upright `i`.

To quote from the `mhchem` manual:

> Typographical conventions say that variables are typeset in italic font, while other entities (like chemical elements) are typeset in an upright font.
>   mhchem tries to recognize common patterns and use the correct (italic) font [...]

To quote from the IUPAC  ['Use of Italic and Roman Fonts for Symbols in Scientific Text'](https://www.iupac.org/home/publications/technical-reports/guidelines-for-drafting-reports/8-use-of-i.html):

> The chemical potential of argon might be denoted m_Ar or m_(Ar), but the chemical potential of the ith component in a mixture would be denoted m_*i* , where the i is italic because it is a variable index.

To achieve an italic index `i` using the `chemformula` package, one can use something like this: `\ch{[Cl^-]_{$i$}}`

Comment: Is there a difference between the upright i and the itshape i in chemical notation? If so, it should be pointed out. Not a chemist here, just noticing different output by the two packages.

Comment: @thymaro - I believe the "i" will generally be a digit, i.e., 1, 2, etc. Unless the text and math fonts are wildly different, nobody will notice the difference between, say, a text-mode "2" and a math-mode "2".